# Create New Column that fills in a different lengthed table based on match

Tags: r

Here I have a table of Site # and Longitude and Latitude (OutputDataWrangle2) and continous site data (outputDataDaily).

[image]

[image]

I need to create a new column that inserts the Coordinates based on if the Site # matches.
Is this possible?

Open to any libraries, not sure where to go.

Comment: Hi @Matt! Could you please edit your question to include your data as reproducible code? Images of data are highly discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12109788). Some tips on editing your question so that the data are reproducible can be found here: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Good luck!

Comment: Also, have you tried `merge(OutputDataWrangle2, outputDataDaily, by.x = "site_no", by.y = "outputDatacoords.site_no")` or `dplyr::left_join(OutputDataWrangle2, outputDataDaily, by = c("site_no"  = "outputDatacoords.site_no"))`?

Comment: Yes, this works!!! A big thank you.